# MEAN-Stack - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: sql, mean-stack

I'm developing a WebApp with MEANStack, using Sequelize to access SQL Databases. Unfortunately I get the following error on the client's side: core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (tables.service.ts:39)

"Line 39" of the error is `applicationsTables: tableData.applicationsTables.map(table => {`

Here's how the DT on the server side looks like:
[Data Table on the Browser - Server Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQTl2.png)

And here's how the error on the client's side looks like:
[Error Messages on the Chrome developers' tools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CPK.png)

Here's my code

tables-list.component.html

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <h1 class="mat-body-2">Process List &nbsp; </h1>

  <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && !isLoading">
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Process List
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="processTables" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated">

      <!-- ProcessName Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ProcessName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ProcessName </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ProcessName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- PackageVersion Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="PackageVersion">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PackageVersion </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.PackageVersion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <!-- RobotType Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="RobotType">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RobotType </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.RobotType}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- PackagePath Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="PackagePath">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PackagePath </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.PackagePath}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- CreationTime Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CreationTime">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CreationTime </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CreationTime}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <!-- Status Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Status}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedprocessTablesColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedprocessTablesColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

    <br> <h1 class="mat-body-2">Applications List &nbsp; </h1>
```

tables-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Table, ApplicationsTable } from "./tables.model";
import { PageEvent } from "@angular/material";

import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { TablesService } from "./tables.service";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";

@Component({
  // We load the component via routing and therefore we do not need a selector
  selector: "app-tables",
  templateUrl: "./tables-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./tables-list.component.css"]
}) // Turn class into component by adding @Component Decorator
export class TableListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  processTables: Table[] = [];
  applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[] = [];
  isLoading = false;
  totalTables = 0;
  tablesPerPage = 5;
  currentPage = 1;
  pageSizeOptions = [1, 2, 5, 10];
  displayedprocessTablesColumns: string[] = ["ProcessName", "PackageVersion", "RobotType", "PackagePath", "CreationTime", "Status" ];
  userIsAuthenticated = false;
  userId: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;

  private tablesSub: Subscription;
  private authStatusSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    public tablesService: TablesService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.tablesService.getTables(this.tablesPerPage, this.currentPage);
    this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    this.tablesSub = this.tablesService
      .getTableUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((tableData: { processTables: Table[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; tableCount: number }) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.totalTables = tableData.tableCount;
        this.processTables = tableData.processTables;
        this.applicationsTables = tableData.applicationsTables;
        console.log(tableData.applicationsTables);
      });
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    // console.log("Is authenticated: " + this.userIsAuthenticated);
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });
  }

  onChangedPage(pageData: PageEvent) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.currentPage = pageData.pageIndex + 1;
    this.tablesPerPage = pageData.pageSize;
    this.tablesService.getTables(this.tablesPerPage, this.currentPage);
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tablesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.authStatusSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Tables.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { Table, ApplicationsTable } from "./tables.model";

const BACKEND_URL = environment.apiUrl + "/tables/";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TablesService {
  private processTables: Table[] = [];
  private applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[] = [];
  private tablesUpdated = new Subject<{ processTables: Table[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; tableCount: number }>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getTables(tablesPerPage: number, currentPage: number) {
    const queryParams = `?pagesize=${tablesPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    this.http
      .get<{ processTables: Table[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; maxTables: number }>(
        BACKEND_URL + queryParams
      )
      .pipe(
        map((tableData: { processTables: Table[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; maxTables: number }) => {
          return {
            processTables: tableData.processTables.map(table => {
              return {
                ProcessName: table.ProcessName,
                PackageVersion: table.PackageVersion,
                RobotType: table.RobotType,
                PackagePath: table.PackagePath,
                CreationTime: table.CreationTime,
                Status: table.Status
              };
            }),
            applicationsTables: tableData.applicationsTables.map(table => {
              return {
                ProcessName: table.ProcessName,
                PackageVersion: table.PackageVersion,
                WorkflowsBelongingToProcess: table.WorkflowsBelongingToProcess,
                ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow: table.ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow
              };
            }),
            maxTables: tableData.maxTables
          };
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTablesData => {
        this.processTables = transformedTablesData.processTables;
        this.tablesUpdated.next({
          processTables: [...this.processTables],
          applicationsTables: [...this.applicationsTables],
          tableCount: transformedTablesData.maxTables
        });
      });
  }

  getTableUpdateListener() {
    return this.tablesUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  getTable(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<{
      ProcessName: string;
      PackageVersion: string;
      RobotType: string;
      PackagePath: string;
      CreationTime: string;
      Status: string;
    }>(BACKEND_URL + id);
  }
}
```

Tables\model.ts:

```
export interface Table {
  ProcessName: string;
  PackageVersion: string;
  RobotType: string;
  PackagePath: string;
  CreationTime: string;
  Status: string;
}

export interface ApplicationsTable {
  ProcessName: string;
  PackageVersion: string;
  WorkflowsBelongingToProcess: string;
  ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow: string;
}
```

Backend\models\tables.js:

Backend\controllers\tables.js:

```
const sequelize = require("../sequelize");

exports.getProcessTables = (req, res) => {
  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Process", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(fetchedtables => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Process table fetched from the server",
      processTables: fetchedtables,
      maxProcessTables: fetchedtables.length
    });
  });
};

exports.getApplicationsTables = (req, res) => {
  sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Applications", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(fetchedtables => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Applications Table fetched from the server",
      applicationTables: fetchedtables,
      maxApplicationsTables: fetchedtables.length
    });
  });
};
```

Backend\routes\tables.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const TableController = require("../controllers/tables")

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get("", TableController.getProcessTables);
router.get("", TableController.getApplicationsTables);

module.exports = router;
```

How can I fix it?
Many Thanks
Gennaro

Comment: Sorry, my answer I posted wasn't right (long day!). Although getting rid of the `any` type makes your code better, it's not the issue as you're not getting a TypeScript error which is what I first read it as! Can you put a breakpoint on the return statement of the map and check what `tableData` is? I suspect it's not the structure you think it is - either tableData doesn't have the tables property or it's undefined. It could be the server that isn't returning the structure in the proper format. If there are no tables, the property should probably be set to an empty array so array methods work

Comment: Dear @GeraintAnderson thanks for your reply. In my original post I have now just added a screenshot on how the server reads the Data table.
The problem is where with Angular, on the client side, I want to read such table.

What else do you need to know? Would you like to have the code structure?

Comment: Dear @GeraintAnderson, I have now added console.log(TableData); as you asked. The tables returned are in the second screenshoot that I have added to my edited post.

Comment: Your return object has a property 'retrievedTables' but you are trying to access 'tables' which doesn't exist. You can fix this in either Backend\controllers\tables.js or Tables.service.ts. To fix it on the server, just change `retrievedTables: tables` to `tables: tables` so the client is getting the fields it expects. If you were to fix it on the client instead you would need to reference retrievedTables rather than tables and update your types accordingly. You're also not sending a `maxTables` from the server so you will want to add that. Perhaps, `maxTables: tables.length`

Comment: I've removed the *mean* tag. It's for arithmetic mean.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson many thanks for your reply, it works! I have also added maxTables but it does not do anything. Now I have 2 additional challenges:
- First Challenge: Although I can read the table in tables.service.ts, I cannot read the table in the next step which is tables.list.component.ts (Please see code in the edited original post and also the client-side console log in the screenshot attached to edited original post.
-Second Challenge: no matter how many Items per page I select, it keeps showing the same (See screenshot attached). What am I missing? Many thanks, Gennaro

Comment: Unless you've implemented a `count` method on the backend tables, you should be using `tables.length` rather than `tables.count`.

Comment: The reason you are getting undefined values in your table properties is because you are mapping them to the wrong property names in the service. The results returned from the server have properties beginning with a capital letter, so `processName: table.processName` should be `processName: table.ProcessName,`.

Comment: As to the paging, I can't see where you are using the query parameters you pass to the server. I'm not familiar with sequelize but I suspect you should be adding the query to the SQL string you are building. The pagesize and page properties are available on the `req.query` object in your backend controller.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson thanks for the email now it works. As of the paging, I have added the additional code tables-list.component.html in the original post. What does not work is limiting the number of elements per page. However, as you can see from the screenshot "tableData variable on the client's side", the max number of items (6 in this case) is correctly read everywhere. What additional info would you need? Many thanks, G.

Comment: I'm not going to be much help with that part as I've not used the libraries but try setting the limit and offset in the database query. Try something like this instead: ` ``SELECT * FROM dbo.Process LIMIT ${req.query. pagesize} SKIP ${req.query.page}`` `. Notice the backticks rather than the double quotes, otherwise you will need to build up the string with concatenation.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson, thanks to your help I was able to advance. I have edited the original post with my new challenge, which consists of adding a second table in addition to the single table that I've been exctracting so far. Any chance you could help? Any chance you could reply in a "Answer" instead of in a "Comment" so that I can mark your answer as helpful?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the second table and what's not working? It might be better to create a new question addressing specifically the new problem. Don't worry about opening lots of questions - it's what the site is for and you will get better answers if you can isolate a specific problem within a question because people will find it easier to help with specific problems.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson thanks for your reply! In my Webapp I need to list multiple tables.  With one table, thanks to your support, it works perfectly. Now, if you read through the code, there is a second table called "Applications". Why can't I read this second table?

Comment: Does the first table still work now that you have edited the `tables.js` file? You could just make two requests from the client and join the tables on the client. Or you could make a single request and the backend code makes the two table queries and sends them back as a single response. Or the backend could make a single query which gets the data from both tables at once using a join. Which one you choose depends how you want to access the data.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson thanks for your reply. Yes tables.js works. But is it possible that the problem is that I do not read getApplicationsTables on tables.js? 

Can you write how to I should modify the code? You listed 3 solutions but I am not entirely sure how to go ahead and fix the code...

You see how I want to access the data: in tables-list.component.html I want to have this second table (actually also a third and a fourth..) in my onePage App.

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson any news? Many thanks

Comment: Hi @GeraintAnderson I have also added backend/routes/tables... Maybe the problem lies there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an object which has a property 'retrievedTables' from the server but on the client you are trying to access 'tables' which doesn't exist.

You can fix this in either `Backend\controllers\tables.js` or `Tables.service.ts`. To fix it on the server, just change `retrievedTables: tables` to `tables: tables` so the client is getting the fields it expects. If you were to fix it on the client instead you would need to reference retrievedTables rather than tables and update your types accordingly. You're also not sending a maxTables from the server so you will want to add that. Perhaps, `maxTables: tables.length`.

You also need to make sure you correctly reference the property names. On the server you are sending table properties with an uppercase first letter and on the client you are reading properties with a lowercase first letter which leads to it being undefined.

Be careful with type definitions too. In this case, you are saying that the tables property of the return object of the `this.http.get` is of type any and then try to call its map method. Only certain types have a map method so be more specific about what you are expecting. Even specifying the type as an array of any types is better as you then guarantee the map method:

```
this.http
.get<{ tables: any[]; maxTables: number }>(
  BACKEND_URL + queryParams
)
```

That could still be improved further by specifying a specific type rather than any, especially as you go on to use its properties. The better type would be the same one used for the return type of getTable which can be defined as an interface for reuse.

```
interface TableInstance {
  processName: string;
  packageVersion: string;
  robotType: string;
  packagePath: string;
  creationTime: string;
  status: string;
}
```

Then, you would define the type returned from get as below.

```
.get<{ tables: TableInstance[]; maxTables: number }>(
```

You can set the type of the map function too, which will work instead of doing the above, which directly addresses the problematic line from your error message.

```
.pipe(
map((tableData: { tables: TableInstance[]; maxTables: number }) => {
  return {
```

Comment: Many thanks @Geraint Anderson, but it still returns the same error. I've edited my original post according to your suggestions. What else should I do? Im worried I got some code wrong on the Backend side, but I dont' know. On the browser, I can visualize the SQL table on the server side easily, but cannot read it on the client side.